# Confusion on the unstable state of a Conical pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

For a conical pendulum at an angle $\alpha$ from the vertical,
$$ cos \alpha = \frac{g}{\omega ^2 l} $$

When $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}$ , $cos \alpha= 1$

That is straight forward.
But How can $cos \alpha $ still be 1 when $\omega > \sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}$ ?

Atleast that is what Kleppner and Kolenkow says:
[image]

Comment: In Kleppner and Kolenkov, just before your quote, they explain that $\sin(\alpha)=0$ and $T=W$ is a solution for all $\omega$. The solution $\cos(\alpha)=\frac{g}{\omega^2 l}$ is obtained from the equations of motion by dividing by $\sin(\alpha)$ which is not valid for $\sin(\alpha)=0$.

Comment: Uff thanks! I feel stupid now : ]